# Problem Type UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two `UIButton` buttons. I have already initialized the buttons in my xib type add in touch after my program I want to change the type of button:

```
configImage1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure] ; //doesn't Work !
configImage2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; //doesn't Work !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the type of the button after you have created it.

Comment: another solution without making a new different view?!

Comment: I don't know. I just know it's not currently possible to change an UIButton type. So just instantiate another UIButton and replace the previous one.

Comment: ok but how I can replace a button in the same location as lotr for which another button

Comment: `UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:newType]; newButton.frame = oldButton.frame;`

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *configImage1 ;  UIButton *traitImage1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; 
  traitImage1.frame = configImage1.frame;

Answer (score 1):

**UIButton**  has the below property but it's readonly, so one can'nt change the button type once it's created,

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIButtonType buttonType
```

Try to Create a new `UIButton` again if you want change in button type ,